# passport-saml and SAML encryption

Tags: node.js, encryption, passport.js, saml-2.0, shibboleth

I'm new to `passport` and `passport-saml`, and I'm trying to build a **Node.js** server that uses our University's Shibboleth identity provider for single sign-on. I'm pretty close to getting it all working, but I'm hitting a snag during the /login/callback that I think is related to the encryption configuration.

I am able to redirect the client to the sign-in page, and after a successful sign-in, the IdP does a POST back to my **/login/callback** route. Then I get this error:

```
Error: Invalid signature at SAML.validatePostResponse (.../node_modules/passport-saml/lib/passport-saml/saml.js:357:21) at Strategy.authenticate (.../node_modules/passport-saml/lib/passport-saml/strategy.js:68:18) at ...etc...
```

This sounds like maybe the certificate I'm passing to the `cert` config setting isn't correct? I'm assuming that the `decryptionPvk` and `cert` config settings supposed to be the private key I used to create my server's cert, and the Identity Provider's HTTPS certificate, respectively? Or should they be something else?

I'm using up-to-date versions of node and all the various modules (express, passport, passport-saml, etc.)

And for reference, here's the server script I'm using to test all of this:

```
"use strict;"

var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require("express");
var morgan = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var saml = require('passport-saml');

var cert = fs.readFileSync('./certs/my-server-https-cert.crt', 'utf-8');
var pvk = fs.readFileSync('./certs/my-server-private.key', 'utf-8');
var uwIdpCert = fs.readFileSync('./certs/our-idp-server-https-cert.pem', 'utf-8');

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done){
    done(null, user);
});

var samlStrategy = new saml.Strategy({
    callbackUrl: 'https://my-domain-name.whatever.edu/login/callback',
    entryPoint: 'https://my-university/idp/entry/point',
    issuer: 'my-entity-id (domain name registered with university IdP)',
    decryptionPvk: pvk,
    cert: uwIdpCert
}, function(profile, done){
    console.log('Profile: %j', profile);
    return done(null, profile); 
});

passport.use(samlStrategy);

var app = express();
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({secret: fs.readFileSync('./certs/session-secret.txt', 'utf-8')}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.get('/', 
    passport.authenticate('saml', {failureRedirect: '/login/fail'}), 
    function(req, res) {
        res.send('Hello World!');
    }
);

app.post('/login/callback',
  passport.authenticate('saml', { failureRedirect: '/login/fail', failureFlash: true }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  }
);

app.get('/login/fail', 
    function(req, res) {
        res.send(401, 'Login failed');
    }
);

app.get('/Shibboleth.sso/Metadata', 
    function(req, res) {
        res.type('application/xml');
        res.send(200, samlStrategy.generateServiceProviderMetadata(cert));
    }
);

//general error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
    console.log('Express error!');
    console.error(err.stack);
    next(err);
});


var server = https.createServer({
    key: pvk,
    cert: cert
}, app);

server.listen(process.argv[2] || 44300, function(){
    console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port)
});
```

Any help or advice would be most appreciated!

Comment: do you not see the solution in the answer and comments below?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the `cert` is the certificate of the identity provider -- not necessarily its HTTPS certificate though.

Your shibboleth identity provider should have a provider metadata document.  If you haven't already, you probably want to make sure the contents of `uwIdpCert` matches the `<ds:X509Certificate>` block in that document.  ([here](https://www.testshib.org/metadata/testshib-providers.xml) is an example of what that metadata document should look like)

If you're pretty sure that the certificates are correct, I'd be curious to see the contents of the xml variable in `SAML.prototype.validatePostResponse`.  (i.e., just throw in a console.log statement and see what it looks like).  There have been some changes to the signature validation logic in passport-saml recently and it's possible your provider is doing something unexpected.

Comment: I debugged into it and the XML was an error message saying "Required NameID format not supported." The default for NameIDFormat seems to be urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress, which I'm guessing our IdP doesn't support. I have an email to our IT folks to ask which value I should use. Also looks like I can set it to null to omit it entirely. Any advice from your end? And thanks for your help!

Comment: BTW, I do return a Metadata document--see the route for `/Shibboleth.sso/Metadata` above. But I thought I was supposed to use my cert when I call `samlStrategy.generateServiceProviderMetadata(cert)`. Are you saying I should use the IdP's cert instead?

Comment: If you find the metadata document, it should have `<NameIdFormat>` tags that tell you waht is accepted.  (for instance, `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient` or `urn:mace:shibboleth:1.0:nameIdentifier` in that TestShib example that I linked to)

Comment: And to answer your second comment -- both you (the Service Provider) and the Identity Provider have metadata documents.  Your comments are about your SP metadata, and you do use your own cert in that context.  In my answer I was refering to the IdP's metadata doc.