# Passport SAML Reply URL/callback switches from https to http

Tags: node.js, passport.js, saml, adfs

I have tried to find answers for this issue before posting the question but unfortunately those solutions have not worked for me so I am posting my questions after exhausting my options

[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20739744/passportjs-callback-switch-between-http-and-https)

[Similar Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24419814/passport-saml-and-saml-encryption)

I am trying to authenticate my `node js` app with `passport saml` and `Azure AD` and I am trying this for the first time.

I have configured the app and following attributes in the Azure portal:

1. Entity ID  https://sampleserver.com/
2. Reply URL  https://sampleserver.com/login/saml/callback
3. Logout URL https://sampleserver.com/logout

This is my passport config

```
passport.use(
        new SamlStrategy(
            {
                path: "/login/saml/callback",
                entryPoint: "https://my-azure-server/ls/adfs,
                issuer: "https://sampleserver.com/",
                decryptionPvk: fs.readFileSync('privateKey.pem'),
                cert: fs.readFileSync('publicCert.pem')
            },
            function (profile, done) {
                console.log("This is what is returned by Saml", profile);
                return done(null, {
                    id: profile.uid,
                    email: profile.mail,
                    displayName: profile.givenname,
                    firstName: profile.givenname
                });
            }
        )
    );
```

The `decryptionPvk` is the key is used to create my server

The `cert` is the certificate I got from my IDP i.e. `Azure`

Problem: When I hit the URL https://sampleserver.com it navigates me to the login URL configured in the application but after the authentication, it gives me the following error:

```
AADSTS50011: The reply URL 'http://sampleserver.com/login/saml/callback' specified in the request 
does not match the reply URLs configured for the application 'https://sampleserver.com/'
```

The callback URL should be `https://sampleserver.com/login/saml/callback` but for some reason the request builds the absolute URL to be `http://sample......` instead of `https://sample...`

I am not able to understand why it picks `http` vs `https`

I have been stuck on this for a couple of days now and I have tried to read as much as possible before posting this question. I would really appreciate some help with this.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps someone who is facing a similar issue but after going through each and every attribute of `SamlStrategy` from the documentation I found something that resolved my issue. Instead of setting `path` in the passport config I set the `callbackUrl` attribute which was the absolute path of the call back URL which made it work

So my config looks as follows:

```
passport.use(
        new SamlStrategy(
            {
                callbackUrl: "https://sampleserver.com/login/saml/callback",
                entryPoint: "https://my-azure-server/ls/adfs,
                issuer: "https://sampleserver.com/",
                decryptionPvk: fs.readFileSync('privateKey.pem'),
                cert: fs.readFileSync('publicCert.pem')
            },
            function (profile, done) {
                console.log("This is what is returned by Saml", profile);
                return done(null, {
                    id: profile.uid,
                    email: profile.mail,
                    displayName: profile.givenname,
                    firstName: profile.givenname
                });
            }
        )
    );
```